# Какой функционал выполняет данный тип файлов?

Tags: typescript, vue3

Ранее работал с `Nuxt.js2` но на данный момент возникла необходимость работать со связкой `VUE3 Typescript`.
Есть такой проект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
Какой функционал выполняет данный тип файлов, выделенный желтыми иконками?
В чем его предназначение?

Comment: никакой, очевидно - это результат сборки находящегося рядом `vue` файла

Comment: Тоесть это не здоровое поведение для дефолтного проекта?
Если да - как его можно пофиксить?

Comment: Вы похоже не верно настроили сборщик) я использую https://vitejs.dev/ и никаких проблем из коробки)

Comment: я вообще его не настраивал это дефолтная установка. )

Comment: почему не здоровое?

Comment: по идее по дефолту не должно быть в проекте ничего подобного.
Но я подозреваю что дело может быть вообще в линтере - проверю в общем при возможности.

Comment: если придумывать варианты - то собранные файлы могут использоваться для инкрементальной сборки, когда собирается только часть которая поменялась, вероятно положение таких файлов в проекте может настраиваться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен убиранием пары опций в настройках линтера для тайпскрипта.

[image: http://joxi.ru/MAjdQLoHdb4b7m]